# React state inside a function is not changing even after calling it with a delay of (5 seconds)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-functional-component, use-state

In react I am using functional component and I have two functions (getBooks) and (loadMore)

`getBooks` get data from an endPoint. But when I call `loadMore` function on button click inside the `getBooks` function (loadMoreClicked) is not changed it uses the previous state even after calling it with a delay of (5 seconds). But when I call `loadMore` again the state changes and everything works fine.

can someone explain why the (loadMoreClicked) on the initial call to (getBooks) didn't update
    even calling it after 5 seconds delay.

```
function component() {
  const [loadMoreClicked, setLoadMore] = useState(false);
  const getBooks = () => {
    const endPoint = `http://localhost/getBooks`; //this is my end point
    axios
      .get(endPoint, {
        params: newFilters
      })
      .then(res => {
        console.log(loadMoreClicked); //the (loadMoreClicked) value is still (false) after (5 sec)
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  };

  const loadMore = () => {
    setLoadMore(true); //here i am changing (loadMoreClicked) value to (true)

    setTimeout(() => {
      getBooks(); // i am calling (getBooks()) after 5 seconds.
    }, 5000);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => loadMore()}>loadMore</button> //calling (loadMore)
      function
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: That's not how state works. State is only updated on re-render, so the value of `loadMoreClicked` will ALWAYS be `false` until your component re-renders. It's not a case of waiting for it to change.

Comment: But when I call (setLoadMore(true)) inside loadMore  function the state has changed and the component should re-render and the state should have updated.after that when I call getBooks after 5 seconds the getBooks should have changed state available

Comment: If I am not wrong component should have re render on calling setLoadMore(true) and the state should have updated. please answer

Comment: No, the component cannot re-render halfway through a function, or the function would stop execution. When you call `setLoadMore`, you are not actually setting state - you are just telling React that you want to set state. React will do this at a later time when the component re-renders. The component will not re-render while you are still inside the function.

Comment: But getBooks is called after 5 seconds. it still don't have the reference to new updated value. Why is this happening. the component should have re rendered with in 5 seconds. But the loadMoreClicked  updated value is still false in getBooks

Comment: The reference to `getBooks` is an old reference. `getBooks` is redefined on every render, but the `getBooks` instance you are referring to is the instance where `loadMoreClicked` equals `false`. It makes perfect sense. This is how closures work. Please read up on closures.

Comment: The comonent does re-render before `getBooks` is called, but the `getBooks` function you are calling is the `getBooks` function declared before the component re-renders, so all the values that `getBooks` has, are the values **before the component re-renders**.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's two things going on:

1. `getBooks()` is using `const` values that are defined in the surrounding function. When a function references `const` or `let` variables outside of its definition, it creates what's called a *closure*. Closures take the values from those outer variables, and gives the inner function copies of the values as *they were when the function was built.* In this case, the function was built right after the state was initially called, with `loadMoreClicked` set to `false`.
2. So why didn't `setLoadMore(true)` trigger a rerender and rewrite the function? When we set state, a rerender doesn't happen instantaneously. It is added to a queue that React manages. This means that, when `loadMore()` is executed, `setLoadMore(true)` says "update the state after I'm done running the rest of the code." The rerender happens after the end of the function, so the copy of `getBooks()` used is the one built and queued in this cycle, with the original values built in.

For what you're doing, you may want to have different functions called in your timeout, depending on whether or not the button was clicked. Or you can create another, more immediate closure, based on whether you want `getBooks()` to consider the button clicked or not, like so:

```js
const getBooks = wasClicked => // Now calling getBooks(boolean) returns the following function, with wasClicked frozen
  () => {
    const endPoint = `http://localhost/getBooks`;
    axios
    .get(endPoint, {
      params: newFilters
    })
    .then(res => {
      console.log(wasClicked); // This references the value copied when the inner function was created by calling getBooks()
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
  }

...

const loadMore = () => {
  setLoadMore(true);
  setTimeout(
    getBooks(true), // Calling getBooks(true) returns the inner function, with wasClicked frozen to true for this instance of the function
    5000
  );
};
```

There is a third option, which is rewriting `const [loadMoreClicked, setLoadMore]` to `var [loadMoreClicked, setLoadMore]`. While referencing `const` variables freezes the value in that moment, `var` does not. `var` allows a function to reference the variable dynamically, so that the value is determined when the function executes, not when the function was defined.

This sounds like a quick and easy fix, but it can cause confusion when used in a closure such as the second solution above. In that situation, the value is fixed again, because of how closures work. So your code would have values frozen in closures but not in regular functions, which could cause more confusion down the road.

My personal recommendation is to keep the `const` definitions. `var` is being used less frequently by the development community because of the confusion of how it works in closures versus standard functions. Most if not all hooks populate consts in practice. Having this as a lone `var` reference will confuse future developers, who will likely think it's a mistake and change it to fit the pattern, breaking your code.

If you do want to dynamically reference the state of `loadMoreClicked`, and you don't necessarily need the component to rerender, I'd actually recommend using `useRef()` instead of `useState()`.

`useRef` creats an object with a single property, `current`, which holds whatever value you put in it. When you change `current`, you are updating a value on a mutable object. So even though the reference to the object is frozen in time, it refers to an object that is available with the most current value.

This would look like:

```js
function component() {
  const loadMoreClicked = useRef(false);
  const getBooks = () => {
    const endPoint = `http://localhost/getBooks`;
    axios
    .get(endPoint, {
      params: newFilters
    })
    .then(res => {
      console.log(loadMoreClicked.current); // This references the property as it is currently defined
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
 }


  const loadMore = () => {
    loadMoreClicked.current = true; // property is uodated immediately
    setTimeout(getBooks(), 5000);
  };

}
```

This works because, while `loadMoreClicked` is defined as a `const` at the top, it is a constant *reference to an object,* not a constant *value.* The object being referenced can be mutated however you like.

This is one of the more confusing things in Javascript, and it's usually glossed over in tutorials, so unless you're coming in with some back-end experience with pointers such as in C or C++, it will be weird.

So, for what you are doing, I'd recommend using useRef() instead of useState(). If you really do want to rerender the component, say, if you want to disable a button while loading the content, then reenable it when the content is loaded, I'd probably use both, and rename them to be clearer as to their purpose:

```js
function component() {
  const isLoadPending = useRef(false);
  const [isLoadButtonDisabled, setLoadButtonDisabled] = useState(false);
  const getBooks = () => {
    const endPoint = `http://localhost/getBooks`;
    axios
    .get(endPoint, {
      params: newFilters
    })
    .then(res => {
      if (isLoadPending.current) {
        isLoadPending.current = false:
        setLoadButtonDisabled(false);
      }
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
 };

  const loadMore = () => {
    isLoadPending.current = true;
    setLoadButtonDisabled(true);
    setTimeout(getBooks(), 5000);
  };

}
```

It's a little more verbose, but it works, and it separates your concerns. The ref is your flag to tell your component what it's doing right now. The state is indicating how the component should render to reflect the button.

Setting state is a fire-and-forget operation. You won't actually see a change in it until your component's entire function has executed. Keep in mind that you get your value before you can use the setter function. So when you set state, you aren't changing anything in this cycle, you're telling React to run another cycle. It's smart enough not to render anything before that second cycle completes, so it's fast, but it still runs two complete cycles, top to bottom.

Comment: But when getBooks called after 5 seconds it should have reference to new value of loadMoreClick. Why it dosen't

Comment: Oooooo, I forgot to reference a third element -- the fact that getBooks() references a const value. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Alright, so I added what I think should work, as well as referencing `const`. As far as why it doesn't work, it's because the state change runs in a different context than the timeout. You created the timeout with const values in the context of the state being false. It doesn't matter when it gets executed. It matters when it gets created.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `useEffect` method to watch for `loadMoreClicked` updates like `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle method and call the `setTimeout` inside that,

```
useEffect(() => {
    if(loadMoreClicked){
      setTimeout(() => {
        getBooks();
      }, 5000);
    }
  }, [loadMoreClicked])
```

this way only after the `loadMoreClicked` is changed to `true` we are calling the `setTimeout`.

This boils down to how closures work in JavaScript. The function given to `setTimeout` will get the `loadMoreClicked` variable from the initial render, since `loadMoreClicked` is not mutated.

Comment: Do callback exist in useState hook in functional component as far as I know it only work with setState of class component

Comment: yeah you're right, callbacks doesn't exsist in `useState` hook, I will edit my answer now according to hooks

Comment: @user8989, i used the `useEffect() ` to watch for changes for `loadMoreClicked`, check if this works?

Comment: But my point is when I call setLoadMore(true) the component should have re render as state changed and state should have updated and loadMoreclicked should have changed to true. but the loadMoreclicked value did not changed even after 5 seconds in getBooks() function

Comment: that is because `setLoadMore(true)` is an async operation and you are calling the `setTimeout()`  right below the `setLoadMore(true)` so at that time the `loadMoreClicked` variable will not be changed to `true` and the `setTimeout` will get the variable `loadMoreClicked` with the value `false` which is then referenced in the `getBooks()`

Comment: I am still unable to understand can you explain deeply and more easily. Is it some what related to closure that's why I am not able to get it